# Accessing geojson properties using OpenLayers3

Tags: geojson, openlayers

Is it possible to access geojson properties using the OpenLayers library? I tried to search for it but couldn't find any proper answer.
According to my research, the library converts each geojson feature to `ol.Feature` which doesn't provide any access to the properties.

For eg:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [102.0, 0.6]
      },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0"
      }
    }
}
```

How can I access `prop0` using the openlayers library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use:

```
feature.get("prop0")
```